# How can I test my website for a different country?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm building an E-commerce website in the Neto framework and I have set up user groups for Kenya and South Sudan as these are countries that the client is selling to. The setup has been fine but I want to test that this is working before sending it to my client. I can use a Proxy or something however I don't know of one that has South Sudan or Kenya. Does anyone have tips for this?

Comment: personally i use zenmate proxy server it is free you can get it as a browser extension and it gives you 4 country to choose between them

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a proxy to do what you want. It will basicly reroute your traffic through another country. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server

Comment: The OP already mentioned using a proxy, but said they didn't know of one that could do those particular countries...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a Virtual Private Network(VPN) for that purpose. [Try this VPN client](https://hola.org/), it will work good enough to test your site worldwide.

Answer (score 0):

You just go with some proxy websites on that county and test,
Example you need to check in Australia, Search proxy sites in Australia. You just enter any one site and give your URL and test it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use vpn(Virtual private network).
it is a private network that extends across a public network or internet.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network